# how to update Status as closed after selection of particular value from picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

Update Lead field Status = Closed if Lead Stage is Booked through trigger

```
public  with sharing class leadController {
     private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
     Public Boolean flagReleasing {get;set;}
     Public Lead lead{get;set;}
     public String selectedstages{get;set;}

 public  leadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        lead=new Lead();  
        this.controller = controller;
        this.lead= (Lead)controller.getRecord();  
        flagReleasing  = false;     
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> Options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Options.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        Options.add(new SelectOption('booking','Booking'));
        Options.add(new SelectOption('booking','Waiting'));

        return Options;
    }

    public PageReference save(){

        return null;
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" showHeader="false" extensions="leadController">
<apex:form >
              <apex:pageBlock title="Updating lead field ">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedstages}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/>
                </apex:selectList>  

                <apex:inputField value="{!lead.lead_Status__c}"/><br/>     

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                               <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>    
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
         </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you try out first and post where you are facing the issue? I can see no code written in the save() method

Comment: No action performed on save button

Comment: i want to display lead_status__c = closed when user select any one value from Pick list .. i.e stage = booked then status=closed

Comment: Need to update a value based on the picklist value before saving the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Add a method in the leadController class which will simply update the lead.lead_Status__c to Closed.

`public PageReference updateLeadStatus(){
    lead.Status = 'Closed';
    return null;
}`

2. Add an Id attribute to the apex:inputField tag to rerender it.

`<apex:inputField id="statusInput" value="{!lead.Status}"/>`

3. Add an action function on the page inside the apex:form tag which will invoke this method and rerender the apex:inputField.

`<apex:actionFunction action="{!updateLeadStatus}" name="updateLeadStatus" reRender="statusInput"/>`

4. Add an onchange attribute on apex:selectList tag to call this action function.

`<apex:selectList onchange="updateLeadStatus()" value="{!selectedstages}" multiselect="false" size="1">`

Comment: tx @Sanket Mandhare